# Qual a melhor forma de atualizar várias tabelas, usando uma trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma trigger para
After insert notas
After delete notas
After update notas

E preciso atualizar várias tabelas como, vendas, vendas_vendedor.

Eu testei usando um cursor pra cada tabela, a princípio funcionou normalmente, minha dúvida e quanto ao desempenho e se há outra forma para implementar.

Segue código implementado:

```
/**********************************************************************************************/
DROP TRIGGER depoisInsertNotas;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE
TRIGGER `depoisInsertNotas` AFTER INSERT ON `notas` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE datan INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE totaln DECIMAL(18,4);

DECLARE codven INT;
DECLARE nomeven VARCHAR(150);
DECLARE vendas CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(notas.datreg, '%Y%m') AS anomes, SUM(notas.totnot) AS total 
FROM notas 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(notas.datreg, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NEW.datreg, '%Y%m') 
GROUP BY anomes;

DECLARE vendas_vendedor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(notas.datreg, '%Y%m') AS anomes, SUM(notas.totnot) AS total, notas.codven, notas.nomven 
FROM notas 
WHERE notas.codven = NEW.codven AND DATE_FORMAT(notas.datreg, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NEW.datreg, '%Y%m')
GROUP BY notas.codven, DATE_FORMAT(notas.datreg,'%Y%m');

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;
OPEN vendas;

done: LOOP 
  FETCH vendas INTO datan, totaln;

  IF done THEN
     LEAVE done;
  END IF;

  CALL deletaNotas(datan, NULL);
  INSERT INTO vendas(anomes, totven) VALUES (datan, totaln);

END LOOP;
CLOSE vendas;

/*********************************************/

SET done = 0;
OPEN vendas_vendedor;

done: LOOP 
  FETCH vendas_vendedor INTO datan, totaln, codven, nomeven;

  IF done THEN
     LEAVE done;
  END IF;

  CALL deletaNotas(NULL, codven);
  INSERT INTO vendas_vendedor(anomes, totven, codven, nomeven) VALUES (datan, totaln, codven, nomeven);

END LOOP;
CLOSE vendas_vendedor;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Tem como por o exemplo da operação que foi feita para desencadear essas alterações? E também como ficariam os dados após as alterações? Também é interessante postar a sua tentativa

Comment: Depende de qual o seu objetivo. Coloque o seu código para podermos avaliar melhor.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, com o código implementado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wribeiro,

A utilização de cursor é muito lento, não é recomendavel utilizar, por si só utilizar TRIGGER já é complicado devido a manutenção posterior, se nao estiver bem documentado é bem facil de esquecer e acabar gerando bugs futuros.

Para resolver a situação você pode utilizar o SELECT com INSERT. exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO banco.tabela-destino (campo1, campo2, campo3...)
SELECT campo1,campo2,campo3... FROM banco.tabela-origem;
```

No seu cenario seria:

```
INSERT INTO vendas(anomes, totven)
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(notas.datreg, '%Y%m'), SUM(notas.totnot)
FROM notas 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(notas.datreg, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NEW.datreg, '%Y%m') 
GROUP BY anomes;

INSERT INTO vendas_vendedor(anomes, totven, codven, nomeven)
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(notas.datreg, '%Y%m'), SUM(notas.totnot), notas.codven, notas.nomven 
FROM notas 
WHERE notas.codven = NEW.codven AND DATE_FORMAT(notas.datreg, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NEW.datreg, '%Y%m')
GROUP BY notas.codven, DATE_FORMAT(notas.datreg,'%Y%m');
```

Comment: eu nao usaria cursor, mas eu ainda precisaria usar um loop pra preencher os dados?

Comment: Não, por que esta sendo usado de dados ja existes que trazidos no SELECT, o resultado do SELECT será todo inserido, se retornar 5 linhas serão novas 5 linhas inseridas.

Comment: Entendi, dessa forma funcionou também, essa forma serve pra Update e Delete?

Comment: para o delete voce consegui usar no proprio WHERE e no UPDATE voce consegui usar fazendo join, exemplo:

UPDATE VEN
SET VEN.Valor = ???
FROM vendas VEN, desta maneira voce consegue fazer o update que voce desejar. Caso precise posso ir colocando mais exemplo para voce ou ajudar voce a montar um update

Comment: Como posso fazer para voce me ajudar com uma trigger no update? edito minha pergunta?

Comment: Acredito que voce precisa lancar uma nova pergunta ai me passa o link que te ajudo.

Comment: segue link da nova pergunta, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/319629/atualizar-tabelas-usando-trigger-a-partir-de-uma-tabela-principal