# Atualizar tabelas usando trigger, a partir de uma tabela principal

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, trigger

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

Uma tabela principal X, onde é armazenado "cabeçalho" da venda.

Uma tabela Y, onde são armazenados os itens da venda.

Uma tabela Z, onde será salvo alguns dados da venda, a partir das triggers disparadas da tabela X.

Nisso, toda vez que for inserido, atualizado, ou deletado um registro, os valores da tabela Z terão que ser atualizados pela trigger.

Segue códigos implementados:

Trigger AFTER INSERT:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS depoisInsertDADF311;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER depoisInsertDADF311 AFTER INSERT ON dadf311 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

/******** ALIMENTA TABELA DADF503 ********/

DELETE FROM dadf503 WHERE anomes = NEW.anomes;

INSERT INTO dadf503(anomes, codreg, nomreg, codsup, nomsup, codven,   nomven, codpro, nompro, codcin, nomcin, valven, qtdven)
SELECT 
dadf311.anomes, dadf311.codreg, dadf311.nomreg, dadf311.codsup, dadf311.nomsup,
dadf311.codven, dadf311.nomven, dadf313.produt AS codpro, dadf313.descri AS nompro, 
dadf313.codcin, dadf313.nomcin, SUM(dadf313.valtot) AS valven, SUM(dadf313.quanti) AS qtdven
FROM 
dadf311, dadf313
WHERE
dadf311.tipnot = 'NS' AND
dadf311.anomes = dadf313.anomes AND
dadf311.filial = dadf313.filial AND
dadf311.tipnot = dadf313.tipnot AND
dadf311.numnot = dadf313.numnot AND
dadf311.sequen = dadf313.sequen  
GROUP BY anomes, codreg, codsup, codven, codpro
ORDER BY qtdven DESC;


/******** ALIMENTA TABELA DADF503 ********/


END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Trigger AFTER DELETE:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS depoisDeleteDADF311;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER depoisDeleteDADF311 AFTER DELETE ON dadf311 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE dadf503 AS vd1, 
( SELECT dadf311.anomes, dadf311.codreg, dadf311.nomreg, dadf311.codsup,    dadf311.nomsup,
dadf311.codven, dadf311.nomven, dadf313.produt AS codpro, dadf313.descri AS nompro, 
dadf313.codcin, dadf313.nomcin, SUM(dadf313.valtot) AS valven, SUM(dadf313.quanti) AS qtdven
FROM dadf311, dadf313
WHERE dadf311.anomes = OLD.anomes AND
dadf311.anomes = dadf313.anomes AND
dadf311.filial = dadf313.filial AND
dadf311.tipnot = dadf313.tipnot AND
dadf311.numnot = dadf313.numnot AND
dadf311.sequen = dadf313.sequen AND
dadf311.tipnot = 'NS' ) AS vd2 
SET vd1.anomes = vd2.anomes, vd1.codreg = vd2.codreg, vd1.nomreg = vd2.nomreg, vd1.codsup = vd2.codsup, vd1.nomsup = vd2.nomsup,
vd1.codven = vd2.codven, vd1.nomven = vd2.nomven, vd1.codpro = vd2.codpro, vd1.nompro = vd2.nompro, vd1.codcin = vd2.codcin, 
vd1.nomcin = vd2.nomcin, vd1.valven = vd2.valven, vd1.qtdven = vd2.qtdven  
WHERE vd1.anomes = vd2.anomes; 

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Minha dificuldade está no SELECT com o WHERE, e se existe uma forma de diminuir essa consulta pra uma forma mais fácil de entedimento, porque visualmente parece "feia".

Comment: Faltou colocar na sua questão um aspeto importante, que é o seu problema atualmente e que dificuldades está a sentir para implementar a solução que pretende!

Comment: Opa, editei a pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso do `delete` você pode usar um subselect no `where` para informar os itens a serem deletados:

```
DELETE z WHERE z.Xid IN (SELECT Id FROM X)
```

No caso do `update` você pode utilizar um "*update com from*":

```
UPDATE z
SET z.Valor = sum(x.Valor)
FROM z z
INNER JOIN x ON x.Id = z.xID
```

Ou até mesmo fazer a soma em um `select` e depois fazer o `update` com a soma.

Comment: Você consegue dar um exemplo em cima das minhas querys? Ainda estou meio confuso rs, porque assim, toda vez que alterar algum dado na tabela principal, ele precisa apagar o registro da tabela secundária, para depois fazer o update com o valor da soma atualizado, no o SELECT SUM().

Comment: crie o schema do bd e me passa o link, pode utilizar esse site http://sqlfiddle.com, ai monto o update para voce, por que ai eu monto e mando para voce sem erro

Comment: Criei o schema aqui, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jhBXw3cgCRq53eArMnc1yK/0  
Tem a tabela principal e as tabelas secundarias, com os scripts que criei.

Answer (score 1):

Na primeira `TRIGGER` organizei o vínculo das tabelas em `JOIN` para simplificar o `WHERE` e dividir responsabilidades. Adicionei também o `WHERE` para o `NEW.anome` que indica que apenas o registro inserido será recalculado. Da forma que estava antes todos os registros eram reinseridos:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS depoisInsertDADF311;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER depoisInsertDADF311 AFTER INSERT ON dadf311
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

/******** ALIMENTA TABELA DADF503 ********/

  DELETE FROM dadf503 WHERE anomes = NEW.anomes;

  INSERT INTO dadf503(anomes,
                      codreg,
                      nomreg,
                      codsup,
                      nomsup,
                      codven,
                      nomven,
                      codpro,
                      nompro,
                      codcin,
                      nomcin,
                      valven,
                      qtdven)
  SELECT dadf311.anomes,
         dadf311.codreg,
         dadf311.nomreg,
         dadf311.codsup,
         dadf311.nomsup,
         dadf311.codven,
         dadf311.nomven,
         dadf313.produt AS codpro,
         dadf313.descri AS nompro,
         dadf313.codcin,
         dadf313.nomcin,
         SUM(dadf313.valtot) AS valven,
         SUM(dadf313.quanti) AS qtdven
    FROM dadf311
         INNER JOIN dadf313 ON dadf311.anomes = dadf313.anomes
                           AND dadf311.filial = dadf313.filial
                           AND dadf311.tipnot = dadf313.tipnot
                           AND dadf311.numnot = dadf313.numnot
                           AND dadf311.sequen = dadf313.sequen
   WHERE dadf311.tipnot = 'NS'
     AND dadf311.anomes = NEW.anomes
   GROUP BY anomes,
            codreg,
            codsup,
            codven,
            codpro
   ORDER BY qtdven DESC;


/******** ALIMENTA TABELA DADF503 ********/


END;
$$

DELIMITER
```

Segui a mesma ideia para a segunda `TRIGGER`:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS depoisDeleteDADF311;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER depoisDeleteDADF311 AFTER DELETE ON dadf311
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

  UPDATE dadf503 AS vd1
        (SELECT dadf311.anomes,
                dadf311.codreg,
                dadf311.nomreg,
                dadf311.codsup,
                dadf311.nomsup,
                dadf311.codven,
                dadf311.nomven,
                dadf313.produt AS codpro,
                dadf313.descri AS nompro,
                dadf313.codcin,
                dadf313.nomcin,
                SUM(dadf313.valtot) AS valven,
                SUM(dadf313.quanti) AS qtdven
           FROM dadf311
                INNER JOIN dadf313 ON dadf311.anomes = dadf313.anomes
                                  AND dadf311.filial = dadf313.filial
                                  AND dadf311.tipnot = dadf313.tipnot
                                  AND dadf311.numnot = dadf313.numnot
                                  AND dadf311.sequen = dadf313.sequen
          WHERE dadf311.anomes = OLD.anomes
            AND dadf311.tipnot = 'NS') AS vd2
      SET vd1.anomes = vd2.anomes,
          vd1.codreg = vd2.codreg,
          vd1.nomreg = vd2.nomreg,
          vd1.codsup = vd2.codsup,
          vd1.nomsup = vd2.nomsup,
          vd1.codven = vd2.codven,
          vd1.nomven = vd2.nomven,
          vd1.codpro = vd2.codpro,
          vd1.nompro = vd2.nompro,
          vd1.codcin = vd2.codcin,
          vd1.nomcin = vd2.nomcin,
          vd1.valven = vd2.valven,
          vd1.qtdven = vd2.qtdven
    WHERE vd1.anomes = vd2.anomes;

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Notei que alguns campos que você atualiza não fazem sentido (como por exemplo o `anome`) mas é interessante que você pense se realmente não faz ou se está certo como está.

Comment: tem alguma diferença em usar o JOIN ou WHERE?

Comment: @wribeiro semanticamente sim. Você pode conferir isso [nesta[(https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join) pergunta.

Comment: beleza, acho que entendi!